# UITableView пагинация

Tags: swift, uitableview

коллеги!

Задача такая - есть массив из примерно 100 элементов данных. В нем уже все лежит, ничего подгружать дополнительно не надо.
При отображении на UITableView, отображаются все 100 элементов.
Необходимо разбить на пагинацию по 10 элементов в таблице. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Используйте секции в TableView ,для того чтобы разделить ваш контент как вам угодно.